# Embedding Javascript in My Application

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9

I want to embed Javascript in my own application.  I know I can do this with all the open source Javascript engines like V8, TraceMonkey/SpiderMonkey.  But, scanning through the source code learning how to embed them is not easy given most are not well documented.  Is there anything native in Windows?  Is the JScript engine already been exposed to user (perhaps through COM)?  Would the JScript engine in IE9 (the one with compilation capability) be available for embedding by desktop appli?

Answer (score 0):

For some languages there are embeddable javascript engines available, that are specifically designed to be used as scripting engines or stand-alone interpreters.
Most popular one is probably [Rhino](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/) for Java. But for .Net there is also [Jint](http://jint.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You can embed the MS-supplied script engines, including JScript and VBScript using the [Script Interfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9d4xf28%28VS.85%29.aspx). But it doesn't look like they're better documented than the open source options.

Answer (score 0):

You could look at [SEE: Simple ECMAScript Engine](http://users.dart.net.au/~leonard/software/see/).  If you read the intro to the ECMAScript standards, you will notice that the language is actually intended to be used to script objects that are native to your application environment.

I think that a big problem with JS is that people conflate it with DOM which is what would kill any language.  Brendan Eich actually set out to implement Scheme in the browser.  So when the marketing types insisted on the Java name and curly brackets language, he took the Scheme & Self concepts and wrapped the C-like syntax around it. Oh and it was branded JavaScript even though it has very little in common with Java - but at the time it was the flavour of the day.

Answer (score 0):

[MuJS](http://mujs.com) is an embeddable JavaScript interpreter, with an explicit focus on being easy to embed and extend. If you're familiar with the Lua C API, picking up MuJS should be easy.